# Azure SQL Database patch and update doubts

Tags: azure-sql-database, upgrade, patching

It is known that Microsoft automates the patch and update of Azure SQL Database. But, some times applications must be tested before being applied any type of patch or update, because there's a possibility to get a failure in the application.

It's is possible for the customer to reverse a patch, or test it and authorize it before being applied?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the customer to reverse a patch, or test it and authorize it before being applied?

No.  It’s part of the service definition that updates won’t break your application.  Any potentially breaking changes, including query optimizer enhancements won’t be active until you opt in by changing your Database Compatibility Level.

See 
https://docs.microsoft./en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017